# Datetime Picker issue in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, datetimepicker

Using the below code I'm able to select the date from the datetime picker.

What is happening is in startdate I'm getting today's date and previous one only whereas in enddate I'm getting date form today onwards as highlighted.

I want after selecting the date in startdate, all the dates after startdate selected should be highlighted in enddate.

```
$(function () {
  $('#event_start_date').datetimepicker({ maxDate: '0' });
});

$(function () {
  $("#event_end_date").datetimepicker({ minDate: '0' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might help you....

```
$(function() {
    $('#event_start_date').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
        showSecond: true,
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            var endDateTextBox = $('#event_start_date');
            if (endDateTextBox.val() != '') {
                var testStartDate = new Date(dateText);
                var testEndDate = new Date(endDateTextBox.val());
                if (testStartDate > testEndDate)
                    endDateTextBox.val(dateText);
            }
            else {
                endDateTextBox.val(dateText);
            }
        },
        onSelect: function (selectedDateTime){
            var start = $(this).datetimepicker('getDate');
            $('#event_start_date').datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(start.getTime()));
        }
    });
    $('#event_start_date').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
        showSecond: true,
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            var startDateTextBox = $('#event_start_date');
            if (startDateTextBox.val() != '') {
                var testStartDate = new Date(startDateTextBox.val());
                var testEndDate = new Date(dateText);
                if (testStartDate > testEndDate)
                    startDateTextBox.val(dateText);
            }
            else {
                startDateTextBox.val(dateText);
            }
        },
        onSelect: function (selectedDateTime){
            var end = $(this).datetimepicker('getDate');
            $('#event_start_date').datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date(end.getTime()) );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i have already used this code, but with the help of this the start date calender is showing all the dates, whereas i want only today and previous date in that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a parameter...

```
minDate: new Date()
```